# Where to store Decoded JSON array from server and how to access it globally in viewControllers?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

Currently im creating application which parses JSON from my server. From server I can receive array with JSON models.
Data from this array must be populated in table View.
My question Is simple: where to store decoded array from server, if I want to access it from many viewControllers in  my application?

Here is my JSON model, which coming from server.

```swift
import Foundation

struct MyModel: Codable {
    var settings: Test?
    var provider: [Provider]
}

extension MyModel {
    struct setting: Codable {
        var name: String
        var time: Int
    }
}
```

here is how I am decoding it

```swift
import Foundation

enum GetResourcesRequest<ResourceType> {
    case success([ResourceType])
    case failure
}

struct ResourceRequest<ResourceType> where ResourceType: Codable {

    var startURL = "https://myurl/api/"
    var resourceURL: URL



    init(resourcePath: String) {
        guard let resourceURL = URL(string: startURL) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        self.resourceURL = resourceURL.appendingPathComponent(resourcePath)
    }


    func fetchData(completion: @escaping
        (GetResourcesRequest<ResourceType>) -> Void ) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, _ , _ in
            guard let data = data else { completion(.failure)
                return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let jsonData = try? decoder.decode([ResourceType].self, from: data) {
                completion(.success(jsonData))
            } else {
                completion(.failure)
            }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better to have a separate class e.g. `CategoriesProvider` and store categories to it. You can pass an instance of `CategoriesProvider` throw all the view controllers. Or you can make CategoriesProvider as a Singleton and have access from any view controller. Moreover, it's better to do `fetchData` from `CategoriesProvider`.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi Bogaevskyi Bogaevskyi Я понял, что вы говорите по русски)) Можно по-подробнее спросить  про Синглтон? Т.Е я создаю класс CategoriesProvider и добавляю туда метод fetch data() ? Там ведь не нужен DispatchQueue? Только когда обращаюсь к этому классу из другого ViewConroller'a?

Comment: да) Когда присваиваете categories в свойство, то DispatchQueue нужен, даже из  CategoriesProvider. Сейчас код напишу в Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of CategoriesProvider. It just stores categories in-memory and you can use them across the app. It is not the best way to do it and not the best architecture, but it is simple to get started.

```swift
class CategoriesProvider {
    static let shared = CategoriesProvider()

    private(set) var categories: [Category]?

    private let categoryRequest = ResourceRequest<Category>(resourcePath: "categories")
    private let dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    private init() {}

    func fetchData(completion: @escaping (([Category]?) -> Void)) {
        guard categories == nil else {
            completion(categories)
            return
        }

        dataTask?.cancel()

        dataTask = categoryRequest.fetchData { [weak self] categoryResult in
            var fetchedCategories: [Category]?

            switch categoryResult {
            case .failure:
                print("error")
            case .success(let categories):
                fetchedCategories = categories
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.categories = fetchedCategories
                completion(fetchedCategories)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest using URLSessionDataTask in order to cancel a previous task. It could happen when you call `fetchData` several times one after another. You have to modify your ResourceRequest and return value of `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...)`

Here more details about data task https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-004 (DataTask and DownloadTask)

Now you can fetch categories in CategoriesViewController in this way:

```swift
private func loadTableViewData() {
    CategoriesProvider.shared.fetchData { [weak self] categories in
        guard let self = self, let categories = categories else { return }
        self.categories = categories
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In the other view controllers, you can do the same but can check for the 'categories' before making a fetch.

```swift
if let categories = CategoriesProvider.shared.categories {
    // do something
} else {
    CategoriesProvider.shared.fetchData { [weak self] categories in
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You can mark the answer as useful if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid duplicate load data() calls, your simplest option would be to cache the data on disk (CoreData, Realm, File, etc.) after parsing it the first time.

Then every ViewController that needs the data, can just query your storage system.

Of course the downside of this approach is the extra code you'll have to write to manage the coherency of your data to make sure it's properly managed across your app.

Comment: I don't want to avoid these calls) Im just not sure if its a good practise. I was searching for a way to save decoded array to other class after first parsing and accesing this array later from another ViewController.

Comment: If your ViewControllers communicate with each other, i.e. VC1 calls VC2, then you can simply pass the parsed data from VC1 to VC2 (dependency injection). If multiple classes need access, then you're better off having one point of truth for your data, that all classes query. Otherwise, there's nothing inherently wrong with calling your server at each class, especially if the data is often modified.

Answer (score 0):

make a global dictionary array outside any class to access it on every viewcontroller.